# Not working fopen in sftp server

Tags: php, sftp

Following code is working well in my local server Xampp as well as remote server. But when I trying with sftp server it is not working.

```
$fptr = fopen("Test File.pdf", "w"); 
    fputs($fptr, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
    fclose($fptr);
```

How can I fix it in sftp server?

Process: Pdf file submit through the submit button. After clicking on submit button from pdf file, this whole file save to server folder.

Comment: I have got answer. The folder was not permitted in server. that is why I was getting no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by not working? Nothing saved? Or there is a error message?

If it is not a problem with your code, I will suggest that it is about the directory you are working on. You might need to check group first then use chmod command to change the protection.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Not working means not save in the relative folder. Same code is working in another server but not working sftp server.

Comment: I was trying with permission but not working. The folder is permitted as 777 and the .php file under this folder is 664. Yet not working, Just echo working. Would you tell me where it should need change?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using Apache? If you are, you want to change the protection of the group "other" to write. 777 seems to be alright, it means everyone can do everything. So this is probably because some other reason.